# could you please use the three following phrases to construct a long sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

'tools made of stone', 'lengends recorded', 'remains found'. These three short phrases,if combained into one sentence, can anyone give a good example?

Comment: it can be something like: Legends recorded that in ancient Egypt tools made of stone were used to build pyramids, and recently some remains found that prove it. By the way, this is a really strange question I have seen posted here. Can you please tell us how come you asked it? I am seriously curious.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Sina that is a strange question, but to answer it the best way I can, you can try: If legends recorded are accurate, the presence of tools made of stone along with ancient remains found in caves in Europe proved early man's capacity to adapt to his environment.